# How can I move the box around the corner

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to move the box around the corner (horizontal from the top-left 
corner to the top-right corner and then you go down to the bottom-right corner.

```js
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p>

<div id="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I prefer **CSS3-ANimation** for these things, Frame animation is smooth and easy to use.
Feel free to us CSS animations as in the code pen link below:

Codepen Link: [**CSS3 ANimation** link](https://codepen.io/pratik-sangami/pen/yLBjNGJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could distances `top` and `left` as below with conditions so that it moves on one direction each time and stop when total distance travelled satisfies the position:

```js
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var left = 0;
  var top = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  elem.style.left = "0px";
  elem.style.top = "0px"

  function frame() {
    if (left < 350 && top == 0) {
      left++;
      elem.style.left = left + "px";
    } else if (left == 350 && top < 350) {
      top++;
      elem.style.top = top + "px";
    } else if (top == 350 && left > 0) {
      left--;
      elem.style.left = left + "px";
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button></p>
<div id="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does half of the work. How can I move it from bottom right to bottom left in the code you provided. Thanks in Tons

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
.classname #animate {
  -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:350px; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:350px; top:350px;}
  75%  {left:0px; top:350px;}
  100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:350px; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:350px; top:350px;}
  75%  {left:0px; top:350px;}
  100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```js
 function ani(){
    document.getElementById('container').className ='classname';
  }
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
.classname #animate {
  -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:350px; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:350px; top:350px;}
  75%  {left:0px; top:350px;}
  100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:350px; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:350px; top:350px;}
  75%  {left:0px; top:350px;}
  100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="ani()">Click Me</button></p> 

<div id ="container">
  <div id ="animate"></div>
</div>
```

you can use css animations as shown below

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:350px; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:350px; top:350px;}
  75%  {left:0px; top:350px;}
  100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
  0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {left:350px; top:0px;}
  50%  {left:350px; top:350px;}
  75%  {left:0px; top:350px;}
  100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
  <div id ="animate"></div>
</div>
```